# How can I mount a large TV over wall molding?

Tags: walls, mounting, studs, television

I want to mount a TV but the trim on the wall is protruding. Would it be possible to use 2x4s going vertically on each side (where the blacks dots are) and then attach the mount to the 2x4s? Thanks in advance.

[image: one image]

Comment: Mark the stud locations on the wall and your desired horizontal center, and update the picture.  Measure the exact trim thickness and put that in the question.

Comment: What's with all the big holes?  Buy stud finder. And use a 1/16"  drill for your poking and prodding.  Later you can fill all the tiny holes and even without painting they won't be considered damage. Landlord expects a coat of paint when you move out.  But if you make Swiss cheese you'll have to pay to redecorate the wall.

Comment: Alternately, simply cut the trim (oscillating multitool?) and pry it off—odds are it's just nailed or glued to the surface.  You can either screw your mount directly to studs if they're in the right position for it, or screw a piece of plywood to the studs, and attach the mount to that.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't need to be fancy or complicated. You just need standoffs that are large enough to not crush into the drywall. Simple 1x2 boards would do just fine. If that doesn't give you quite enough depth to clear the molding, add washers *over* the boards as needed or go with a two-by.

I'd run a pair of 1x2 or 1x3 boards behind the mount, vertically at the stud locations. They should extend at least a couple inches above and below the screws to prevent drywall damage by spreading load.

Note that the mount screws will still need to reach the studs. The shim boards do not carry load directly. 3" lag screws would probably be appropriate. Pre-drill the boards to the screw size and the studs to slightly smaller than the screw *shank* size.

Don't over-tighten the screws--you *can* crush the drywall that way. Just snug them lightly. Consider putting waxed paper behind the boards so they don't stick to the wall paint over time.

```
    : :                            : :
    :_:                            :_:
    | |                            | |
    |*|                            |*|
    | |                            | |
    | | <-- blocks --------------> | |
    | |                            | |
    |*| <-- mount screws --------> |*|
    | |                            | |
    :‾:                            :‾:
    : : <-- studs ---------------> : :
    : :                            : :
```

Answer (score 5):

If you anchor it solidly into studs, you can definitely shim it.

I'd make two shims, as large as well fit in those gaps, just slightly proud of the trim. Then place a 1/2" plywood panel over it, the screws going through the shims into the studs in the wall. Make sure you use several construction screws that hold the plywood+shim assembly tight against the wall.

Attach the TV mount to the plywood and you're good to go.

Do not just put the plywood over the trim and try to just crush it when you tighten the screws. You want the shims flat against the wall, and the plywood flat against the shims.

Comment: They make mounts that will mount on one stud.

Comment: Is there any way u can provide an imagine of the shims/plywood combination, i think I understand what you mean but i just want clarification, do you mean to put layers of shim in the left and right spaces of the wall trim? Aka where i put the black dots? And then put 1 piece of plywood on each side ? I dont want to damage the trim bcuz im renting the apt so i wasnt intending on just ruining it im trying to use the small space that is there on each side of it

Comment: @Gil a one stud mount for a 70 inch TV ?

Comment: @LunDawg one continuous piece of plywood stretching across both shims to give you a "new wall" to which you then attach your TV mount. You need to be certain though that there are studs in the wall behind where you mount the shims! You can't mount a large TV just to the drywall.

Comment: The key to this answer (and to the answer I would have written if this answer did not already exist) is that the "black dots" are 100% irrelevant. The only locations on the wall that matter are **where the studs are**. Shims need to cover those locations, and ideally some more so that the plywood is mounted flat against a larger area. But the studs are what matters. It is likely that at least one stud will be in the "black dot" area, but it is total guesswork.  There are a bunch of stud finding methods from gadgets to knocking to drilling tiny holes - whatever works for you. Once you find the

Comment: studs, follow the rest of this answer and you will be all set.

Comment: Yes it would work with a 70 inch. Use the manufacturers ratings and I believe it was a 80" max. I have one and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single stud mount: [Single Stud Full-Motion TV Wall Mount for 32" to 80" TVs](https://shop.sanus.com/en_US/products/tv-mounts/olf15/).

Comment: While such a gizmo may not actually collapse, it's going to feel rickety and be difficult to keep level. I know this from experience with much smaller TVs on similar mounts. I'd never use hardware like that at the upper extremes of its claimed load range, especially when the load range is so huge.